# My Vue and index.js are not working together

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Why is my Vue and index.js import not working?
In my live server the text just shows up as {{ message }}
the html and js files are located in the same directory

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pomodoro Timer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>

</body>

</html>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Comment: First of all you should always put custom css/js after plugins or frameworks you include so index should go after vue file

Comment: @Raul Thanks what you mentioned has worked for me!